# How likely is it to get a no-pair AND no-flush 6 card hand?

Tags: probability

My friend and I were discussing this problem for a class and I wanted to see if someone could explain what we're doing wrong.

If you are dealt a 6 card hand from a standard 52 card deck, what is the probability that get a no-pair AND no-flush hand? That is, no repeated faces, and no suit appears more than four times.

We have $${\binom{13}{6}\cdot4^4\cdot\binom{4}{2}\over\binom{52}{6}}\approx.1295$$

but I have a feeling that with such strict criteria, this probability is *way* too high. Can anyone tell me what we're not seeing?

Comment: I'm not sure your conditions are _that_ strict are they? Flushes are pretty rare so that requirement shouldn't have too big an effect.

Comment: @aPaulT okay it might not be, but it's just intuition that's telling me that ~13% is a bit too high for this hand...I mean, I could be wrong.

Comment: I'd break it down into two steps - calculate the no-pair probability, then the probability of no flush given no pair (this should be simpler to work out since all the cards are different ranks so their suits are independent). I _think_ you'll get an answer quite a bit higher than 13%. Also try dealing a few dozen hands and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

I see that what I suggested in my last comment is actually pretty much what you already did. So I think your approach is basically right, but the problem is with your $4^4\cdot\binom42$, which I take it is counting the choices for the suits. For the first four cards you have free choice, but then the last two are only restricted if the first four have three the same suit (otherwise you've already avoided a flush), so your $\binom{42} as a simple factor added in doesn't work.

It's probably easier to count the number of flush arrangements then subtract it from $4^6$. There are 4 possibilities with all 4 cards the same suit, and then $4\cdot3\cdot4=48$ possible five-card-flushes (four choices of five-card suit, each with three choices of suit for the other card, and four choices of position for the other card). So the suits part of the expression should be $6^4 - 48$. With that replacement I think the probability evaluates to about 0.341.